# PowerShell script to add an M365 license to unlicensed users

Tags: powershell

I have the following script that I've tried to put together to find unlicensed users with a specific subdomain @students.contoso.com and then apply the correct license SKU to make the unlicensed user, correctly licensed.  The user exists in Azure AD and M365 Admin centre.

```
# Specify the license SKU you want to assign to users
$LicenseSku = 'contoso:STANDARDWOFFPACK_STUDENT'

# Get all users in the students.contoso.com subdomain
$Users = Get-MsolUser -All | Where-Object { $_.UserPrincipalName -like "*@students.contoso.com" }

#foreach ($User in $Users) {
    # Check if the user is unlicensed
    if ($User.isLicensed -eq $False) {
        # Assign the license to the user
        Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $User.UserPrincipalName -AddLicenses $LicenseSku
        Write-Host "Assigned license to $($User.UserPrincipalName)"
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Set-MsolUserLicense : Unknown error occurred.
At line:11 char:9
+         Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $User.UserPrincipalNam ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Set-MsolUserLicense], MicrosoftOnlineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.OperationNotAllowedException,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.SetUserLicense
```

I'm struggling to find the cause here as the error is 'unknown'.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you

Expect to find all unlicensed users in the subdomain @students.contoso.com and apply the correct SKU as defined in $LicenseSku.